# How to write tests to my 3 functions?? I'm struggling with it:(

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, pypdf

```
import sys
import PyPDF2
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
from gtts import gTTS
import os

# our pdf file
book = "think.pdf"

def main():
    check_file()
    readText()
    generate_audio()

# checking file type
def check_file():
    if not book.endswith(".pdf"):
        sys.exit("File isn't a pdf!")

# looping through our book's text
def readText():
    with open(book, "rb") as f:
        pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
        myText = ""
        for pageNum in tqdm((range(pdf.numPages))):
            time.sleep(0.3)
            pageObj = pdf.getPage(pageNum)
            myText += pageObj.extractText()

# converting text to audio
def generate_audio():
    fileOutput = gTTS(text=myText, lang="en")
    print("Generating Speech...")
    value = fileOutput.save("audio.mp3").time()
    os.system("start audio.mp3")
    print("Successfully Generated!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my functions don't take parameters and don't have inputs, didn't know writing tests would take longer than writing the entire app's code, I didn't write tests before I'm a noob, tried assert and nothing worked fore example this:

```
from project import check_file, readText, generate_audio
import pytest

def test_check_file():
    assert check_file(".pdf") == True

def test_readText():
    pass

def test_generate_audio():
    assert generate_audio() == "audio.mp3"
```

Comment: A detail: writing `== True` is useless. It is also, in my opinion, ugly.

Comment: It is perfecly normal that writing the tests take a lot of time. They are not a waste, they are a very important part of any serious project.

Comment: One of the reasons it is difficult to write tests for these functions is that they use things which are, in my opinion, bad practices. For instance, the function which is supposed to check the file type exits the entire program, instead of returning False or raising an exception. Also, all the functions seem to have side effects, which is both a dangerous practice and a serious obstacle for testing.

Comment: bortzmeyer is absolutely correct -- To put it another way, if you find that writing tests is hard, it may be a sign that you need to refactor.

Comment: "*my functions don't take parameters and don't have inputs*" If you make them take parameters, testing would be a lot easier. Part of the value of tests is to reveal how flexible or inflexible your functions are.

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are hard to write, this suggests your code is inflexible, using bad practices, and needs to be refactored.

1. Global variables. Globals are generally a bad idea. Using globals means you can't test your functions with a variety of inputs.
2. Side-effects. A side-effect is anything that a function does rather than accepting and returning values. Using globals and calling functions like `sys.exit` are examples.
3. Logic vs side-effects. Sometimes side-effects are necessary, but if you combine them together with logic you can't get one without the other. The rule of thumb is a function should perform logic *or* have a side effect.

Something like this.

```
import sys
import PyPDF2
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import logging

def main():
    book = "think.pdf"

    if not check_book_filename(book):
        sys.exit("File isn't a pdf!")

    text_to_speech(
        get_book_text(book), "audio.mp3"
    )

# Describe what the function does in the name.
# Take all inputs as arguments.
# Return the result of the check.
# No side effects.
def check_book_filename(book):
    return book.endswith(".pdf")

# Describe what the function does in the name.
# Take all inputs as arguments.
# Return the result.
# No side effects.
def get_book_text(book):
    with open(book, "rb") as f:
        pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
        myText = ""
        for pageNum in tqdm((range(pdf.numPages))):
            # What is the sleep for?
            time.sleep(0.3)
            pageObj = pdf.getPage(pageNum)
            myText += pageObj.extractText()
    return myText

# Describe what the function does in the name.
# Take all inputs as arguments.
# Use a logger rather than printing. The logger can be mocked and tested.
# No logic, only side effects.
def text_to_speech(myText, filename="audio.mp3"):
    fileOutput = gTTS(text=myText, lang="en")
    logging.info("Generating Speech...")
    fileOutput.save(filename)
    os.system("start " + filename)
    logging.info("Successfully Generated!!")

import pytest

def test_check_book_filename():
    assert check_book_filename("test.pdf")
    assert not check_book_filename("test.jpg")

def test_get_book_text():
    # You need to provide a sample PDF and its expected text.
    assert get_book_text(some_pdf) == expected_text

# There isn't much you can usefully test here except that there is
# a file. Maybe you could check that it's a valid MP3, but
# for now just check it contains something.
def test_text_to_speech():
    audio_file = "tmp/test.mp3"
    text_to_speech("this is a test", audio_file)
    assert os.path.getsize(audio_file) > 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```